# Arrange particles in the shape of a rectangle

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a particle simulation program I'm currently working on that generate random particle positions in a rectangular shape. This works for now but it's not the best solution, often particles overlap and there are small holes in the rectangle. How would I initialize the particles in the shape of a rectangle?

My current loop:

```
for(auto i=0; i<MAXPARTICLES; i++){
    int particleIndex = FindUnusedParticle();           //grab the index to give a particle life
    ParticlesContainer[particleIndex].life = 100.0f;    //Long particle life

    //generate random positions for particles in the shape of a box with random patterns
    ParticlesContainer[particleIndex].pos = glm::vec3((rand()%50)/5.0,(rand()%50)/5.0,-50.0);

    // Very bad way to generate a random color
    ParticlesContainer[particleIndex].r = 255;
    ParticlesContainer[particleIndex].g = 0;
    ParticlesContainer[particleIndex].b = 0;
    ParticlesContainer[particleIndex].a = 255;

    ParticlesContainer[particleIndex].size = .2f;

}
```

Comment: First thing would be to stop using `rand()` because it's an obsolete and limited solution. The second would be elaborating on "particles overlap and there are holes". Do you want them distributed *evenly* (as in, giving optical sense of scatter), or *uniformly* (as in with linear probability over the position)? Randomization will give you the latter.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I'm currently using `rand()` because it's just the easiest way to create a rectangle shape out of particles. I'd want the particle distributed evenly across a given area

Comment: he means use facility provided in C++11 included in [<random>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/)

Comment: `// Very bad way to generate a random color` I enjoyed that bit.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it was guaranteed random by a fair dice roll.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Ah that's okay then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a more complicated problem than just using uniform distribution over two dimensions separately. If your "evenliness" is the distance between two closest particles, then there are exactly two ways to achieve that: equilateral triangles and squares (well, three if you count hexagons). The only random thing there is the position of one seed and the "direction" in which that will go.

Refer to the image:

[image]

That will give you a very regular, grid-like look, though. You could try applying random, minuscule changes to particles distributed that way, and see how that would work.